# Command to close Shared Folder session of Other client machine

Tags: powershell, batch-file

How we can delete particular folders and sub-folder that were open by other user in network share when other client machine open the share path having the write access to that folder.. psfile and net files command will close the file session of client machine but again after few seconds(1-2) it will create automatically another session for that user in server...

do we have any batch command to permanently kill the session of all connection in a particular shared path?

Following is the command i use in net files but this shows the process will create again within 2 seconds after killing it.

```
for /f "skip=4 tokens=1" %a in ('net files') do net files %a /close
```

the above command will close the session but immediately after 1-2 seconds another session will be created

Comment: Please rewrite this to an actual question

Comment: I am still not understanding the context here...

Comment: slashp Edited .. is it possible for you to answer

Comment: I got this example code from Microsoft site... https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290585 using this

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
openfiles /Disconnect /s host /OP "path\to\file.exe" /ID * /u "username" /p "password".
```

**Explain comand:**

**openfiles /disconnect**

Enables an administrator to disconnect files and folders that have been opened remotely through a shared folder.

1. /disconnect -> to close the file.
2. /s -> host  from file, exemple: 192.168.1.10.
3. /op -> full path of file, exemple: "C:\projects\file.exe" .
4. /id -> id of process, when you pass "*" is same than all ids.
5. /u -> user with permission to close file in remote server.
6. /p -> password from user.

Comment: Could you explain why this works, this will improve the value of the answer to the site.

Comment: On this link has a full comand description, [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/openfiles). This command close all session from sharing file in servers.

Comment: Please could you add that to your answer, comments, according to site rules should be used for requests for clarification. Also if you could give the information in the link in your answer that would be better as links can change. Thanks for joining us on Stack Overflow